# how to be able to go to the detail view by clicking on the row of the table reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i want show data row in new  table when i clicking on any item on row
Here's my sandbox

> https://codesandbox.io/s/r56jjoj334

The following pic is the result :

[image]

Comment: Could you paste and format the relevant code in your question instead of linking everything ?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you rendering everything in a table?

If I get it correct you want to render only the names and when clicked upon you want to show the details.

You could simply render all the names as buttons:

```
_renderButtons = items =>
    data
      .slice(
        this.state.activePage * this.state.itemsCountPerPage,
        (this.state.activePage + 1) * this.state.itemsCountPerPage
      )
      .map(item => (
        <>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
          {item.first_name}
        </button>
        {this._renderDetails()}
        </>
      ));

render() {
    var { items, isLoading } = this.state;
    if (!isLoading) {
      return <div> loadding....</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          {this._renderButtons(items)}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

When a button is click, save it in your state however you like. Upon save when render shall be evoked again you can simply check if you need to display the details or not:

```
_renderDetails = () => {
    // check if you need to render
    return(
      <table>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>{item.first_name}</td>
        <td>{item.last_name}</td>
        <td>{item.company_name}</td>
        <td>{item.city}</td>
        <td>{item.state}</td>
        <td>{item.zip}</td>
        <td>{item.email}</td>
        <td>{item.web}</td>
        <td>{item.age}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
    );
}
```

Hope this helps.

You can style your button and tables to have it the look you want.

Comment: Thank you very much